# Web Scraper Function not grabbing new data

Tags: python, pandas, function, web-scraping

I'm having some issues with a web scraping function that I created.

First I created functions to tidy up my code:

```
def get_reviews(string):
    index = string.find('Reviews')
    review = string[index - 10: index + 10]
    reviews.append(review.strip())
```

```
def append_institute(institute):
    if institute is not None:
        institutes.append(institute.text.strip())
    else:
        institutes.append(-1)
```

```
def append_provider(provider):
    if provider is not None:
        providers.append(provider.text.strip())
    else:
        providers.append(-1)
```

```
def append_date(date):
    if date is not None:
        dates.append(date.text.strip())
    else:
        dates.append('Self Paced')
```

```
def append_rating(rating):
    if rating is not None:
        ratings.append(rating.text.strip())
    else:
        ratings.append(-1)
```

```
def append_name(name):
    names.append(name)
```

Then I created the webscraper:

```
def get_data(pages):
    names = []
    institutes = []
    providers = []
    dates = []
    reviews = []
    ratings = []
    for page in pages:
        r = requests.get(page)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        rows = soup.select('tbody tr')

        for row in rows:
            #name
            name = row.select_one('span',{ 'class': 'text-1 line-tight'}).text.strip()
            append_name(name)

            #institute
            institute = row.find('a', {'class': 'color-charcoal small-down-text-2 text-3'})
            append_institute(institute)

            #provider
            provider = row.find('span', {'class': 'hidden medium-up-inline-block'})
            append_provider(provider)

            #date
            date = row.find('td', {'itemprop': 'startDate'})
            append_date(date)

            #reviews
            rev = row.find('span', {'class': 'large-down-hidden block line-tight text-4 color-gray'})
            string = str(rev)
            get_reviews(string)

            #rating
            rating = row.find('span', attrs = {'class': 'xlarge-up-hidden color-charcoal text-center'})
            append_rating(rating)
            
    df = pd.DataFrame({'name': names,
                         'institute': institutes,
                         'provider': providers,
                         'date': dates,
                         'review': reviews,
                         'rating': ratings})
    return df
```

However when I call the get_data function, I get the error: name 'names' is not defined. I tried referencing the empty arrays before the function and that worked. However, it only allows me to run the function once since the values in them get stored. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please put all your code and outputs inside of code blocks! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: A thought just occurring to me: I don't actually return anything in my append functions in the webscraper. I just figured they were local variables so they would reset everytime I ran the function.

Comment: @Landon On it. Reading up on how to put output into code blocks now.

Comment: In`get_data` you are overwriting with a new `df` on each iteration, and then for each datatype you create a new empty list on each call... move all those `names =[]` an such lines to the start of your main function and append or extend on each iteration, then create `df` after exiting the loop

Comment: @RichieV Ah I see that creating the dataframe was included in the loop. I must have glanced over that. I added all of the empty arrays at the start of my main function but now I'm getting the error that 'names' is not defined due to my append_name function etc.

Comment: Try to fit it all in one function, perhaps you are mixing up namespaces... it is hard to tell if you paste in comments, better to edit the question now that there are no answers

Comment: @RichieV I updated the question to my current code. I know I could go about this by simply emptying out the arrays before each call, however I would preferably keep my code neater. Any thoughts?